# Populate Gridview with Adomd Cellset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, ssas, adomd.net

How do you display a SSAS Cube ADOMD cellset in a grid view?

This is my current code, however, it is merging all 3 columns in to one column

e.g.

instead of display

```
col1    col2
1         a
2         b
3         c
```

It is displaying

```
formatted text
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

How do I correct this? This is my code:
            OLAPCellset = OLAPCMD.ExecuteCellSet()

```
        grd1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        grd1.DataSource = OLAPCellset.Cells
        grd1.DataBind()
```

Comment: please show what you are doing